# JavaScript - How to create custom API listener for Socket.io events?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

i'm trying to create custom **API listener** for 3-rd developers on my site. It should look like this:

```
// Function will be fired when any user joins to room
API.on('user-join', function(data){
  console.log(data); // Data is object with user id and name
});
```

I have **Socket.io listener** too:

```
// This handler is fired every time when anyone joins
socket.on('user-join', function(data){
  // Probably here i should call a callback to API.on('user-join') with that data object
});
```

How can i send callback in Socket.io handler to my custom created API? Please let me know how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but if I understand correctly, you want to map the "on" function of the socket.io API to your API.

The best way to do this would be to implement a function like this:

```
API.on = (eventName, callback) => {
    socket.on(eventName, callback);
}
```

Where eventName is a string and callback a function.

This way, you can add an event listener to your API, the same way you would with Socket.io
Eg:

```
API.on('testEvent', (obj) => {console.log(obj});
```

Comment: It will be working with multiple listeners? Example for `user-join` or `user-leave`?

Comment: It will work the same as the socket.io API because it's a mapping to their function

Answer (score 1):

you are mixing things up.

your socket API will need a server-side listener independent from your socket API, that, as far as i understood, manages the IO with the connected clients, am i right?

In this case, you don't have to bind anything. You need a controller for your API sockets and your client's controller have to trigger events to those users.

- a client connects to your site
- a notification is received by the server
- the server notifies to the API users

here's some pseudocode, please don't use it, it just illustrates a concept :D

```
const thrdUsers = [.....] // socket connections
const onThirdUserConnects = socket => thrdUsers.push(socket);
API.on('connect', onThirdUsersConnects);

// Then you need a broadcast function to send events to all your clients
const broadcastToAPI = (msg, val) => thrdUsers.forEach(s => s.send(msg, val));

// Your users will trigger events to your socket.io service
socket.on('whatever-event', (data) => {
  //...Do stuff
  // notify the API clients
  broadcastToAPI('whatever-event', data);
});
```